Is it possible to run multiple instances of JobManger in HA for Flink deployed by Kubernetes Operator 1.9
Basically, we have a lower environment cluster that we are using for multiple environments [Dev, QA, STG].  So I have deployed the Flink Kubernetes Operator 1.8 in a Flink Namespace, then the first JobManager in flink-dev namespace, a second one in a flink-qa namespace, and the last one in the flink-stg namespace.  The only way I can get the JobManagers to work is to remove the high-availability annotations.  If I add the high-availability annotations, I am getting the error further below:
P.S My annotations in my FlinkDeployments are as follows:
env.java.opts.jobmanager: '-Dkubernetes.max.concurrent.requests=1000'
high-availability.storageDir: 'file:///flink-data/ha'
high-availability.type: kubernetes
jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 1024m
state.checkpoints.dir: 'file:///flink-data/checkpoints'
state.savepoints.dir: 'file:///flink-data/savepoints'
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: '20'

The file flink-data is from a mounted azure storage volume with readwritemany privilege.  I have one in each of the flink namespaces.
So it is possible to run multiple Job Managers in different namespaces in HA?  If so, what am I doing wrong that I keep getting the error with the config-map not being able to be updated?
Thanks in advance for any help.
Error Message:

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.persistence.PossibleInconsistentStateException: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.shaded.io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: PUT at: https://172.1.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/flink-dev/configmaps/flink-v-119-cluster-config-map. Message: Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps "flink-v-119-cluster-config-map": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=409, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=configmaps, name=flink-v-119-cluster-config-map, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps "flink-v-119-cluster-config-map": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Conflict, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).


In case, anyone runs into this issue, I got it to run properly on my AKS cluster by adding the following annotations to the Flink deployment, please adjust the values for you own cluster:
high-availability.kubernetes.leader-election.lease-duration: 300s
high-availability.kubernetes.leader-election.renew-deadline: 90s
high-availability.kubernetes.leader-election.retry-period: 15s

I also had to change high-availability.storageDir to use wasbs protocol since I was using an azure storage container.
The full annotations was as follows:
high-availability.storageDir: wasbs://flink-container@xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/
high-availability.kubernetes.leader-election.lease-duration: 300s
high-availability.kubernetes.leader-election.renew-deadline: 90s
high-availability.kubernetes.leader-election.retry-period: 15s
high-availability.type: kubernetes

